How to get latest update from Redis FT search after update by JSON SET
I'm learning redis and working on the scenario that WEB API return available uniqued ticket to client when they request.
I store the ticket record in redis as JSON
"{\"Id\":\"305b1cea-c7be-42b6-9edd-01e5e5f77400\",\"Status\":\"booking\",\"BookingId\":\"c5b2a5dc-3b4b-4a6f-99f9-7a74dc147f07\",\"EventId\":\"510b9ffc-ab61-4872-b01e-6fbb70c495fd\",\"ExpireDate\":638479101043920909}"
the status can be "available" and "booking"
My code is

acquire the lock
use FT.SEARCH to query tickets that have status = "available"
update tickets from 2. to status = "booking" using JSON.SET
return the tickets

I use JMETER to send the 50 requests at a time and found that some response have the same ticket ID
and from investigating if I found that the FT.SEARCH return the record with available which is different from FT.SEARCH that I run in the redis-cli. Look like FT.SEARCH from code not see the update.
My question is how to update the record and query the latest update one, so that the records will be not duplicated?
here is my code
public async Task<List<Ticket>> GetTickets(ILogger logger, int numberOfTicket, Guid bookingId){
   while(!db.StringSet("lock", "lock_value", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), When.NotExists));      
   var res = ft.Search("idx:tickets", new  Query("@Status:\"available\"")).Documents.Select(x => x["json"]);

   var result = res.Select(c => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticket>(c)).Take(numberOfTicket).ToList();
   foreach (var ticket in result)
   {
       ticket.BookingId = bookingId;
       ticket.ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
       ticket.Status = "booking";
       var t = new
       {
           Id = ticket.Id.ToString(),
           Status = "booking",
           BookingId = ticket.BookingId?.ToString(),
           EventId = ticket.EventId.ToString(),
           ExpireDate = ticket.ExpireDate?.Ticks
       };
       while (!await json.SetAsync("ticket:" + ticket.Id.ToString(), "$", t)) ;
   }
   string lua_script = @"  
        if (redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]) == ARGV[1]) then  
            redis.call('DEL', KEYS[1])  
            return true  
        else  
            return false  
        end  
        ";
   db.ScriptEvaluate(lua_script, new RedisKey[] { "lock" }, new RedisValue[] { "lock_value" });
   return result;
}


I try to create new instance of db, ft, and json but it is not working
from debugging look like ft.search not see effected record when the record was updated by JSON.SET
if I use FT.SEARCH in redis-cli it show the record with "booking" status
I use SE.Redis-v2.6.122.38350

